# Making Ajax calls execute more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load an changed image into a modal box with ajax. For example, the photo changes to the selected one when I click "Make Profile Picture" but it keeps the old one showing in the modal box unless I refresh the page. Is there a way to have ajax execute not just on page load but perhaps execute always to check the photo is the new one?

Here is the code I have in place:

PHP -

```
public function getprofileimageAction()
{
    $layout = $this->layout();
    $layout->setTerminal(true);

    $view_model = new ViewModel();
    $view_model->setTerminal(true);

    $params = $this->identity();

    $dir = @array_diff(@scandir(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $params . '/current/', 1), array('.', '..'));

    if (!$dir) {
        // set default avatar
        $string_img = "<img src=\"/images/profile/defaults/avatar2.png\" class=\"w3-round w3-border\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('a-modal').style.display='block'\"
        style=\"width: 200px; height: 200px;\" alt=\"Avatar\" id=\"avatar\">";
    } else {
        $string_img = "<img src=\"/images/profile/$params/current/$dir[0]\" class=\"w3-round w3-border\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('a-modal').style.display='block'\"
        style=\"width: 200px; height: 200px;\" alt=\"Avatar\" id=\"avatar\">";
    }

    $data = array(
        'profile_photo' => $string_img
    );

    echo $data['profile_photo'];

    return $view_model;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery -

```
 var replaced_src;
 var replace;

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/members/profile/get-profile-image",
}).done(function(data) {
   $("#profile-pic").html(data);

   replaced_src = $("#avatar").attr('src');

   replace = replaced_src.replace(/(defaults)/g, '');

  // fix this so it loads the changed image.
  $('#current-photo').html("<img src='" + replace + "' alt='Avatar' class='w3-center w3-round w3-border' style='height: 280px; width: 400px;'>");


 }).fail(function(data) {
    alert("Error loading image");
});
```

This is the event click to change the profile picture

```
$('#make-profile-photo').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/members/profile/change-profile-picture",
        data: { image: $('#other-photo').attr('src') }
}).done(function() {
    document.getElementById('p-modal').style.display = 'none';

    $('#profile-pic').load('/members/profile/get-profile-image');
});
```

});

HTML -

```
<div class="w3-modal" id="a-modal">
        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-theme-d2 w3-round" style="width: 432px;">
            <div class="w3-container">
                <p class="w3-center w3-small">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('a-modal').style.display = 'none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
                    Current Profile Picture
                </p>

                <br>

                <p id="current-photo" class="w3-center">
                <br>
                </p>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var modal = document.getElementById('a-modal');

                    window.onclick = function(event) {
                        if (event.target == modal) {
                            modal.style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                </script>

                <div class="w3-clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So basically what I am asking is if there is a way to reload the changed image so `$('#current-photo')` will display it without having to refresh the page.

Hope that makes sense

Thanks!

If it helps, here is a screenshot of my issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya1NH.jpg

Comment: making an ajax call to check if the image has changed would be very wasteful of resource. What you can do instead is add you ajax call to get the image inside the callback of the function you use to upload the image.

Comment: that worked, thanks!